# Sql Server 2012 cal licence model

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, licensing, cal

I´m currently evaluating the adquisition of a MSSQL 2012 standard edition license, however this is my problem:

I'll have around 100 different users logging through the same application on the same server (RDP), so the server will see 100 connections with the same login and host + 1 management user which could be on different devices.

The hardware is not new so we'll be using a 2 core xeon

because the sql server will get 2 different logins, I should get:

```
(898) Server licence +<br />
(418) 2 CAL user licences <br />
(1316) Total <br />

is this right?, or the server will see:
(898) Server licence +<br />
(209) 1 CAL device licences <br />
(209) 1 CAL user licences <br />
(1316) Total <br />

or:
(898) Server licence +<br />
(209) 1 CAL device licences <br />
(20,900) 100 CAL user licences <br />
(22,207) Total <br />
```

which would be excessive and i better go for a core license model and get:`<br />`
(7,172) a 4 core licensing model

Can you guys point towards more information on the license model i should go for?, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start here for the official word:  http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/client-access-license.aspx

You could also look here, for a user-interpreted answer:  https://serverfault.com/questions/120276/how-are-sql-server-cals-counted

For your situation, you need either CORE licenses that come in 2-core packs, or **server + 100 user CALs**. You will need more than 100 device CALs because if your workers connect to the RDP servers from multiple devices, each DISTINCT end-connection device will require 1 CAL.